# Is there any file/class holding constants for each keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular i'm binding data with host listener, like below code

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    this.onEnterClicked(event);
  }
}
```

and in this code I want to replace `13` with something **Keycode.ENTER**.
but there is no class available which holds constants for each keys in angular and javascript.

so is there any class i'm missing? if not then why javascript or angular not defined constants at one place?

Comment: did you checked `event.key`, it returns string. `event.keyCode` returns `13` and `event.key` returns string `Enter`

Comment: @Akhil Aravind yes i checked, but still in that case I have to wrote constant value `Enter` at the place of `13`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want

```
if (event.key === KeyEventEnum.Enter) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (event.key === KeyEventEnum.Escape) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (event.key === KeyEventEnum.Shift) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (event.key === KeyEventEnum.Ctrl) {
   ...
}
```

instead of you are using like

```
if (event.key === "Enter") {
...
}
```

Angular doesn't have any constant or enum to hold all key code in one place but if you want any enum or constant then you please visit once to below link might be it help you.
Its a angular package that you have to include it in your project.

https://github.com/nfriend/ts-keycode-enum

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, but is there any reason angular or javascript not doing the same thing, even it is widely used class.

Comment: your answer baited me to this package

Comment: To clarify, the linked package doesn't have anything to with Angular. It's pure TypeScript, and will work in any TS project.

Comment: @Elezar, you're correct...

Answer (score 2):

##### KeyCode is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

To understand what would be typed we should use `e.key`, ie `shift+a` results in an uppercase `A`.

To understand what physical button was pressed we should use `e.code`, ie pressing left shift will give us `ShiftLeft`.

Enums for both of these can be found the npm pacakge [etsoo/shared](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@etsoo/shared), or in its [Keyboard Enums source file](https://github.com/ETSOO/Shared/blob/master/src/Keyboard.ts).

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`, `keyCode` returns `13` for enter and `event.key` returns `"Enter"` string

```
 HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
    onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.onEnterClicked(event);
      }
    }
```

Comment: event.key seems better than event.keyCode, but still i have to compare with string and need to search each key like `KeyQ` for `q` etc. and also there may be chance of spelling mistake.

Comment: @RaviSevta, I dont think that javascript have such options, but it sounds easy

Comment: thanks for your time, but i think javascript should have such options.

Comment: @RaviSevta , keep searching, if you find a solution dont forget to post it here, Cheers.. :D

Answer (score 0):

A NPM [@etsoo/shared](https://github.com/ETSOO/Shared) includes:

- `Keyboard.Keys` for `KeyboardEvent.key` constants
- `Keyboard.Codes` for KeyboardEvent.code constants
  It may help.